# how to write a simple GUI application in VisualC++

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-c++

I wanted to do a simple GUI application in VC++ but can't find any good tutorial for same.
I till now just worked in C,linux so dont know how to actually do that. If anyone can point me to some simple "Hello world" GUI application, it will be of great help.

With this, I wanted to know is there any special things I need to do if I am going to do some file IO operations with the GUI application.

I basically have to do the following:-
1) Provide a browse option for user to provide a Path to C file.
2) Read the file.
3) Modify certain content.
4) Put it back.

If anyone can provide me any pointers it will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w9eycd%28VS.80%29.aspx

Another good link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w2f38k(v=VS.90).aspx